# regex replaceAll pattern does not work in Trino UDF

Tags: java, hive, trino

I am working on Trino UDF. Basically i want to remove '/r/n','/r' and '/n' from the string.

The below code does not work if regex with replaceAll is used in Trino. The same code functionality inside the method works fine in hive UDF and as well as tested in java.

```
public static Slice rmcc(@SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) Slice string)
{
String text = string.toStringUtf8();

String regex = "(\\x0D\\x0A|\\x0D|\\x0A)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
String result = m.replaceAll(" ");
return Slices.utf8Slice(result);
}
```

Below code works fine with replace.

```
String text = "hello\nhello\rhello\r\nhello";

String result = text.replace("\\r\\n", " ").replace("\\r", " ").replace("\\n", " ");
```

output should be: hello1 hello2 hello3 hello4

I want to use regex pattern and achieve in replaceall function. please help if i am missing anything.

TIA.